# error in Django RestFrameWork "NOT NULL constraint failed: qoura_question.author_id "

Tags: python, django

trying to add a post to DRF which takes the information of USER and TIME automatically, But this is the error which pops up when tried to add a Post.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 2000)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User , on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views.py:

```
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication,SessionAuthentication]

    def create(self, request):

        obj = Post()
        obj.title = request.data['title']
        obj.description = request.data['description']
        obj.date_posted = request.data['date_posted']
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

serializer.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id', 'title','description','date_posted','author')
```

Comment: Please post error logs which you are facing.

Comment: could it be that you are using `obj.user` in Views.py but should use `obj.author`?

Comment: @deR_Ed this helped, but I still can't see the username in the post detail, it just displays user id for some reason.                                                                                       "id": 2,
        "title": "test layout",
        "description": "this is just something which is generally used to fill in description post 3",
        "date_posted": "1111-12-21T11:11:00Z",
        "author": 1

Comment: I don't know why you bothered to define a serializer, since you *completely ignore it* in your view.

Comment: so how do i do it properly now? Added this one now "obj.author = request.user"  @DanielRoseman